# If I changed from Windows to Ubuntu, would I have to re-install all my programs?

Tags: transfer

So i'm thinking of changing from Windows to Ubuntu, but don't know if I would need to reinstall everything as some windows programs are uncompatible with linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have to re-install everything. Many programs that are available for Windows are available for Ubuntu, and if not, there are usually alternatives that do the same thing. In the case that some program isn't available for Ubuntu, you could try using it with Wine, but that doesn't work all that well, and if you get the program to even load, it is often buggy.

Comment: In the ubuntu setup is there an option to wipe your hard drive? Because I might aswell just copy important files onto a memory stick and install all applications back.

Comment: @skunkdonkey Yes, I believe there is options to completely re-format your HDD during the install process.

Comment: Ubuntu is not Windows. You cannot just install all your Windows apps. The only way new users should install software is from Ubuntu repository. It has just about anything you normally want but not Windows programs. Most dual boot as they have one application or game the must have that does not have an equivalent in Linux. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromWindows